# Value error: Calling 1inch contract with web3.py but having problems with the ABI

Tags: solidity, web3.py, abi, decentralized-exchange

i am trying to get the quote from 1inch regarding the Ethereum/DAI price. I am new to Web3.py and need some additional help regarding the following problem.

My code:

```
import json
from web3 import Web3

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/<My Infura ID>'))

one_inch_split_abi = json.load(open('abi/one_inch_split.json', 'r'))
mcd_abi = json.load(open('abi/mcd_join.json', 'r'))

base_account = "0xA5E421c63b2314ae93c20D5f6021De44DF650b56"

def one_inch_get_quote(_from_token, _to_token, _amount):
    '''
    Get quote data from one inch split contract using on-chain call
    '''
    # load our contract
    one_inch_join = w3.eth.contract(
        address=one_inch_split_contract, abi=one_inch_split_abi)

    # make call request to contract on the Ethereum blockchain
    contract_response = one_inch_join.functions.getExpectedReturn(
        _from_token, _to_token, _amount, 100, 0).call({'from': base_account})

    # logger.info("contract response: {0}".format(contract_response))
    return contract_response

mcd_contract_address = w3.toChecksumAddress('0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f')  # DAI Token contract address

ethereum = w3.toChecksumAddress('0xEeeeeEeeeEeEeeEeEeEeeEEEeeeeEeeeeeeeEEeE') # Ethereum address

one_inch_split_contract = w3.toChecksumAddress('0xC586BeF4a0992C495Cf22e1aeEE4E446CECDee0E') # 1inch address


ethereum_price = one_inch_get_quote(ethereum, mcd_contract_address, w3.toWei(1, 'ether'))

print(ethereum_price)
```

With this code in python i get the following error message:

ValueError: Could not format value {"Here is the code within the 1inch ABI"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I had an invalid ABI imported. Please make sure that your ABI code is wrapped within [].

Comment: Excellent. Remember to come back and mark your answer as correct. You can do it after a day or so.